# Build picture with graph api

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I wonder if it is possible to make a picture using the Facebook graph api.

Lets say you have a timeline template and then you call the graph to get cover pic and profile pic.

Then you'd need to put those in the right places on the template.

I use the standard login with Facebook SDK javascript and then call the graph for cover and profile pic.

I dont know if that is possible but if some one have a clue on how to do that i would love to hear it.

I like to make mockup timeline for the users on my homepage so thats why i want to know.

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly with the Graph API there is no way, what you do with the results is up to you though. You can either build a HTML template and include the data/images, or - if you really want to create a picture - use the GD library: http://php.net/manual/book.image.php